# Чтение файла с помощью службы Win

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-service

Всем привет.

Создал службу, на C# (я не спец...), которая по ходу должна читать *.xml и выполнять задания.

Появилась проблема при запуске служба вылетает - полагаю это связано с чтением xml. тк без нее служба запускается и работает нормально. вот пример кода:

```
    namespace Backup1cSrvInstaller
    {
        public class WinServiceInstaller2 : ServiceBase
        {
            private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            const string MyServiceName = "Backup1C";

            public WinServiceInstaller2()
            {               
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                logger.Trace("[WinService] -> service onSTART");
                Task.Run(() => Foo(10));
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
                logger.Trace("[WinService] -> service onSTOP");

            }

            async void Foo(int taskCount) {
                int delay = 10000;
                //AppService appSrv = new AppService();
                DataService dataSrv = new DataService();

                while (true) {
                    logger.Info("[WinServiceInstaller] -> TASK START [***** Starting new block *****]");

                    List<Data> datas = dataSrv.readXml();

                    /*
                    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                    foreach(Data data in datas){
                        logger.Info("[WinServiceInstaller] -> For-1");
                        Schedule sc = data.ScheduleObj;
                        for(int i=0; i<sc.Days.Count; i++){
                            logger.Info("[WinServiceInstaller] -> For-2");
                            if(dt.DayOfWeek.Equals(sc.Days[i])){
                                logger.Info("[WinServiceInstaller] -> IF-1");
                                for(int j=0; j<sc.Times.Count; j++){
                                    logger.Info("[WinServiceInstaller] -> For-3");
                                    //DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(sc.Times[j].);
                                    if(dt < sc.Times[j]){
                                        logger.Info("[WinServiceInstaller] -> IF-2");
                                        logger.Info("[TASK] -> TASK START -> ID: " + data.Id + ", Name: " + data.ShortName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    */

                    /*
                    for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
                        int index = i;
                        await Run(delay, index);
                    }
                   */  
                }
            }
            async Task Run(int delay, int taskIndex) {
                //Console.WriteLine("Do some operation, index is: {0}", taskIndex);
                logger.Info("Do some operation, index is: " + taskIndex);
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }




        }
```

В общем вот такая вот проблема. а вообще xml читаема, тк. ее читает основной интерфейс другая прога. а это хотел запилить службу с заданиями ...

Но я уверен что то именно с методом чтения xml...

читаю вот так (и вероятно в это и заключается проблема)

```
        ...
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(fileName);
        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlElement xnode in xRoot) {
         ...
```

Так а как тогда его читать ???

Comment: ошибка то какая?

Comment: @tym32167 - а я ХЗ, пока что плохо разбираюсь в шарпе (служба кидает 1067) уверен только в том что это связано с чтением файла, тк только что проверил чтение файла через FileStream то открыло его нормально и начала работать без сбоев

```

             FileStream fs =
                 new FileStream("list.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
             fs.Close();

```

Comment: EventLog глядели?

Comment: @tym32167 вот что в логах

System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Backup1C 
 
  - EventID 0 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 
 
   Level 2 
 
   Task 0 
 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2019-05-21T21:48:10.000000000Z 
 
   EventRecordID 262472 
 
   Channel Application 
 
   Computer Funt-Home 
 
   Security 
 

- EventData 

   Невозможно запустить службу. Процесс службы не может установить связь с контроллером службы

Comment: @tym32167 вероятно ***нашел*** проблему, и она как всегда банальная ***проблема с путем к файлу xml*** ` xDoc.Load("C:/list.xml") ` - начало работать ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел проблему, и она как всегда банальная проблема с путем к файлу xml, когда заменил путь на `xDoc.Load("C:/list.xml")`  - начало работать ... почему так? да потому что у сервиса WorkDir = C:/Windows/System32/ и соответственно оно и файлик ищет там же...

Но на этом все не закончилось!!!

Что бы динамически подтягивать файл xml, я начал запускать сервис с параметрами, в качестве параметра начал кормить путь к этому xml.В итоге получилось вот так. запуск сервиса со стороны внешнего (основного) интерфейса (тк у меня есть прога в которой просто кнопки и набор статического ф-ла, а сервис мне нужен для автоматизации этого ф-ла, и соответственно сервис запускается через этот интерфейс), в общем кусочек кода - вот:

```
        public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
            service.Start({Path.GetFullPath("list.xml")});
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        } catch {
            // ...
            logger.Error("[WinService] -> TASK START");
        }
    }
```

а в самом сервисе метод onStart() принимет переменное число параметров т.о. получилось вот так:

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        logger.Trace("[WinService] -> service onSTART");
        AddLog("start");

        Task.Run(() => Foo(args[0]));
    }
```

Остальной код приведен выше в определении проблемы